# Where is std::hardware_destructive_interference_size?

Tags: c++, c++17

It looks like `std::hardware_destructive_interference_size` isn't defined in libc++ or libstdc++. I've grepped my local installations. I've looked in the respective svn repositories.

They're supposed to be in the `<new>` header, see: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size)

I'd expect people to be asking where these constants are, but apparently nobody else seems to be missing them.

What am I missing? Where are they!

Comment: gcc may not simply have implemented that symbol yet. That's the obvious answer. This is C++17, and this is not the only part of C++17 that's not yet implemented. I'm patiently waiting for to/from_chars overloads for floating point types...

Comment: These constants can cause serious ABI issues, so it isn't surprising that they haven't been implemented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither library has implemented this feature. This is documented on their C++17 compliance status lists:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017

http://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html

(On each, search for 'P0154R1'.)

You may be able to detect whether the feature is available via

```
#if __cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size >= 201603
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017), GCC has not yet implemented this feature.

```
Feature      | Proposal | Status | SD-6 Feature Test
constexpr... | P0154R1  | No     | __cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size >= 201603
```

Same for libc++ [documentation](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html):

```
Paper   | Group | Paper Name   | Meeting      | Status | First released version
P0154R1 | LWG   | constexpr... | Jacksonville | -      | -
```

The support for C++17 of both implementations is still incomplete:

Comment: Note that the second link in this post does not work (anymore).