# Can vector cause false sharing

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, false-sharing

I'm working with C++11 on a project and here is a function:

```
void task1(int* res) {
    *res = 1;
}

void task2(int* res) {
    *res = 2;
}

void func() {
    std::vector<int> res(2, 0); // {0, 0}
    std::thread t1(task1, &res[0]);
    std::thread t2(task2, &res[1]);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return res[0] + res[1];
}
```

The function is just like that. You see there is a `std::vector`, which store all of the results of the threads.

My question is: can `std::vector` cause false sharing? If it can, is there any method to avoid false sharing while using `std::vector` to store the results of threads?

Comment: Yes, and you would need each element to be one its own cache line.  You could create an allocator to decide how memory should be allocated.

Comment: Undefined behaviour occurs as a result of unsequenced operations that need to be sequenced.  In your code, as it stands, the two tasks do not access the same object (`int`), so there are no unsequenced operations that need to be sequenced and the only way for false sharing (e.g. incoherency between cache lines that affects program behaviour if the two tasks run on distinct CPUs) would be a compiler bug. If you change the code so (say) the two tasks modify the *same* `int` (e.g. `task1()` does `res[1] = 5`) then all bets are off.

Comment: @Peter I kind of don't understand. So you are saying that in my piece of code, the compiler should be smart enought to avoid false sharing, if not, it would be a compiler bug?

Comment: @Peter: I disagree with your previous comment. [False sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) occurs if several threads write to the same cache line, so that the CPU must assume that sharing has occured, even though it hasn't. This is likely what happens in OP's code. I strongly disagree with your statement that a "compiler bug" would be necessary for false sharing to occur in OP's code.

Comment: @Peter: The C++ memory model more or less requires that it run on a machine with coherent caches between cores.  As long as the two objects are distinct, it must be possible to access them concurrently and have everything work, without data races - even if they happen to be in the same cache line.  And on a coherent cache machine, having the two ints share a cache line is only a problem for performance (cache ping pong) but not for correctness.  But it's the performance hit that OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @Peter: You're right that on a machine without coherent caches, the compiler would have to put every object, no matter how small, in a separate cache line, and failing to do so would be a bug.  But this would be incredibly wasteful of memory and so we are not likely to run C++ programs on such a machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can std::vector cause false sharing?

Containers aren't something that "cause" false sharing. It's writing to objects that may cause false sharing. Specifically, writing in one thread to an object that is in the same "cache line" as another object that is accessed in another thread causes false sharing.

Elements of an array are adjacent in memory and hence adjacent small elements of an array are very likely in the same cache line. Vector is an array based data structure. The pattern of accessing the elements of the vector in your example are a good example of false sharing.

> is there any method to avoid false sharing while using std::vector to store the results of threads?

Don't write into adjacent small elements of an array (or a vector) from multiple threads. Ways to avoid it are:

- Divide the array into contiguous segments and only access any individual segment from a separate thread. The size of the partition must be at least the size of the cache line on the target system.
- Or, write into separate containers, and merge them after the threads have finished.

Comment: So, if I use two seperate containers, they won't cause false sharing even if they are declared together in the same function? e.g. `std::vector<int> sub1(...), sub2(...);`. In this case, multi-threading writing into `sub1` and `sub2` won't cause false sharing even if they are declared together?

Comment: @Yves If you were to do something that modifies the vector object itself such as push_back, then false sharing would be possible since those vectors would likely be in the same cache line. But the elements themselves wouldn't be, so modifying them wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I am not sure if it is safe to rely on the contents of two `std::vector` containers to be on different cache lines. For example, according to [this link](https://prog21.dadgum.com/179.html), the "smallest allowed allocation" of dlmalloc on a 64-bit system is 32 bytes, which is less than the size of a cache line on most platforms. Therefore, depending on the implementation, it seems quite possible for them to be on the same cache line.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you write to two adjacent `int` elements inside a `std::vector`, it is likely that they will both be on the same cache line, which will cause false sharing if this cache line is accessed simultaneously by two different threads.

C++17 introduced [`std::hardware_destructive_interference_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size), which is a portable way to get a hint from the compiler on what the L1 cache line size is expected to be on the target platform.

Therefore, to prevent false sharing, you should ensure that the two `int` variables are at least `std::hardware_destructive_interference_size` bytes apart:

```
void func() {

    constexpr int min_offset = std::hardware_destructive_interference_size / sizeof(int);

    std::vector<int> res( min_offset + 1, 0 );
    std::thread t1( task1, &res[0] );
    std::thread t2( task2, &res[min_offset] );
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return res[0] + res[min_offset];
}
```

However, at the time of this writing, several compilers do not (yet) support `std::hardware_destructive_interference_size`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60004804/12149471) for further information.

If you want to be reasonably certain that your code will not have false-sharing in the distant future, then you may want to assume that the cache size is double the size reported by `std::hardware_destructive_interference_size`.

Comment: This seems overly pessimistic. Shouldn’t the number of elements in the vector be based on `hardware_destructive_interference_size / sizeof (int)`? +1.

Comment: Not L1 cache size, but L1 cache **line** size. Also, note that neither libstdc++ nor libc++ have implemented it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Yes, you are right. I forgot to divide by `sizeof(int)`. I believe that I have fixed it now.

Comment: @eerorika: Yes, you are right. I intended to write "cache line size". I have fixed it now.

Comment: Another option is to wrap your `int` in a struct type defined with `alignas(std::hardware_destructive_interference_size)`, and have a vector of those instead.  Then each one gets a whole cache line to itself.  In effect you have a vector of cache lines.